# AutoHotkey escape *

Tags: escaping, autohotkey

I want /*{TAB} to be changed into:

```
/*********************************

*********************************/
```

, so I can easily create a comment-block (in PHP). However, when I use

```
:*://`t::
/****************************************{ENTER}{TAB}
****************************************/{ENTER}{LEFT 38}
return
```

It returns some error. :(

How to fix this?

Comment: `Error: this line does not contain a recognized action.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close... The reason for the error "this line does not contain a recognized action" is that you're not telling AutoHotKey what to do with the text, i.e. you need to add `Send` commands to the start of each line.

This is quite a lot closer:

```
::/**::
    Send, /*********************************{ENTER}{TAB}{ENTER}
    Send, ****************************************/{ENTER}{LEFT 38}
Return
```

Things to mention:

- It actually uses <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> to activate it, rather than the <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>*</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> that you wanted. This is because I couldn't get the text editor I was using to pass the <kbd>Tab</kbd> character through to AutoHotKey.
- Depending on how your editor handles the 2nd `{ENTER}`, you might need to add some backspaces, to delete auto-indentation at the start of the next line.

Comment: Wait.. what? I re-loaded this page several time, but your answer did not appear?! :/

I like typing `/**` better than typing `/*`t` every time btw, it's a lot more intuitive and logical. :)


By the way, it seems that my solution is quicker. The text appears in a millisecond. Thanks for your input. :3

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out myself. If someone needs the same: I used:

```
:*:/*`t::
/{+8}****************************************************{ENTER}{TAB}{ENTER}{LEFT}
****************************************************/{ENTER}{LEFT 57}
return
```

Enjoy!